# how do I multiply two variables in javascript if my form is in a for each loop?

Tags: javascript, php

This is my form which is inside a foreach loop
I want to display the product of two input which is the "qty" and "uprice"
but the only result I get is the first row I inputed.

**Form**

```
   <tbody>
    <?php foreach($_POST['porder'] as $porder): ?>
     <tr>
      <td>
            <input type="text" id="itemnum" name="itemnum" max=999 class="form-control form-control-line">
      </td>
      <td>
            <?php echo $porder ; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input style="text-transform:uppercase"  type="text" id="rev" name="rev" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input  style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" id="desc" name="desc" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input type="number" id="qty<?=$porder?>" name="qty[]" min="1" class="form-control form-control-line" onkeyup="compute('<?=$porder?>')" required>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input type="number" id="uprice<?=$porder?>" name="uprice[]" min="1" class="form-control form-control-line" onkeyup="compute('<?=$porder?>')" required>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input type="number" id="amount<?=$porder?>" name="amount[]" onkeyup="stotal('<?=$porder?>')" class="form-control form-control-line" >
      </td>
      </tr>

<?php endforeach ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" ></td>  
    <td><strong>Total
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="number" id="total" name="total"  class="form-control">
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

**Java Script**

---

```
<script>
    function compute() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('qty').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('uprice').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('amount').value = result;
  }
}
</script>
```

---

**Total**
this is the code I use to compute the total amount but it didn't show the result.

```
        var amount = document.getElementsByName('amount[]').value;
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <amount.length; i++) {
        var input_value=amount[i];
        sum +=parseInt(input_value.value);
        document.getElementById('total').value = sum;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: **Note** - the `id` attribute must always be unique

Comment: Like @CarlBinalla said, the `id` attribute must be unique. Javascript will only select the first occurence of an id it finds and ignore all the others. Instead you should probably use a `class` attribute and [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). That will return you an array of all the fields and not just the first one. After that it's a simple matter of looping through that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to below this code. You will get the correct result. '$product_id' means your product id from your database table. that is auto incremented.

**Form**

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($_POST['porder'] as $porder): ?>
     <tr>
      <td>
            <input type="text" id="itemnum" name="itemnum" max=999 class="form-control form-control-line">
      </td>
      <td>
            <?php echo $porder ; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input style="text-transform:uppercase"  type="text" id="rev" name="rev" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input  style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" id="desc" name="desc" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input type="number" id="qty<?=$product_id?>" name="qty" min="1"  class="form-control form-control-line" onkeyup="compute(<?=$product_id?>)" required>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input type="number" id="uprice<?=$product_id?>" name="uprice" min="1" class="form-control form-control-line" onkeyup="compute(<?=$product_id?>)" required>
      </td>
      <td>
            <output type="number" id="amount<?=$product_id?>" name="amount" class="form-control form-control-line" >
      </td>
      </tr>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
    function compute(id) {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('qty'+id).value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('uprice'+id).value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('amount'+id).value = result;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: just want to ask another question on how to get the total of all amount inputed?

Comment: Sorry bro, i was out of office. So couldn't response you.

Comment: sorry I edit your answer I thought it was my question

Answer (score 0):

```js
var qty = document.getElementsByName('qty[]');
for (var i = 0; i <qty.length; i++) {
var input_value=qty[i];
    alert("First Index of Array :  qty["+i+"].value= "+input_value.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="qty[]" id="qty1" type="number" value="1">
<input name="qty[]" id="qty2" type="number" value="3" >
<input name="qty[]" id="qty3" type="number"  value="4" >
```

Comment: is this for total quantity or for total amount.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var qty = document.getElementsByName('qty[]');
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <qty.length; i++) {
var input_value=qty[i];
    alert("First Index of Array :  qty["+i+"].value= "+input_value.value);
    sum +=parseInt(input_value.value);
}
alert("Sum is "+sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="qty[]" id="qty1" type="number" value="1">
<input name="qty[]" id="qty2" type="number" value="3" >
<input name="qty[]" id="qty3" type="number"  value="4" >
```

Comment: What issue you are facing ?

Comment: and I need it to show live without clicking any button or alert.

Comment: you can see it in my question.

Comment: Okay wait , let me offer prayer. Then i will open laptop then i send your answer. Actually on mobile it's not opening properly. Give 15 to 20 minutes. Here 6:00 am

Comment: It's okay, take your time.

Comment: Please check the below answer.

Comment: Is your problem fixed now John?

Comment: Changed snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It will fix your problem. Change the value of input, you will get the result.

```js
function calc(){
var qty = document.getElementsByName('qty[]');
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <qty.length; i++) {
var input_value=qty[i];
//        alert("First Index of Array :  qty["+i+"].value= "+input_value.value);
    var signle_value_input = input_value.value;
    if(signle_value_input.length!=0)
    sum +=parseInt(input_value.value);
}
$("#sum").html("Sum is "+sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sum"></div>
<input name="qty[]" id="qty1" type="number" value="" onkeyup="calc()">
<input name="qty[]" id="qty2" type="number" value="" onkeyup="calc()">
<input name="qty[]" id="qty3" type="number"  value="" onkeyup="calc()" >
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201941/discussion-on-answer-by-kaleemullah-how-do-i-multiply-two-variables-in-javascrip).

Comment: Sure, next time will Care about it